# Competitiveness of online algorithm

Tags: online-algorithms

Is it possible for an online algorithm to perform better than the optimal solution for the offline version of a problem, and if so, in what circumstances?

Doesn't competitive ratio rely on the fact that online algorithm can only reach at most the same performance as the optimal offline solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Say there exists some optimal online algorithm $A$ that is better than any offline algorithm. We can create an offline algorithm $A'$ such that when $A'$ receives the input sequence, it will not perform any preprocessing; instead it will feed each request to $A$ one at a time. This offline algorithm must be optimal, given that $A$ is optimal and better than any other offline algorithm.

With this, the performance of the online can never be better than the optimal offline one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an online algorithm, you can always execute it offline by feeding the elements one at a time, and there's no loss of efficiency. So offline can beat online, and not conversely.